# Double Factorial Sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Let $ n!!$ to be $ n(n-2)(n-4)\ldots3\cdot1$ for odd $ n$ values and let $ n(n-2)(n-4)\ldots4\cdot2$ for even $ n$ values. Also let $ \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{2009} \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}$ be expressed as a fraction in lowest terms, the denominator is $ 2^{x}y$ with $ y$ odd. Find $ \displaystyle \frac{xy}{10}$.

Obviously,the numerator is always an odd number, and the denominator is always an even number.

Letting $S_k$ be the $kth$ partial sum,  I made out:

$S_4 = 7/8, S_6 = 57/48$

But there is no general pattern available.

I used the form they give and:

> $$(2n)!! = 2n*2(n - 1)*2(n - 2)...2(1) = 2^n (n!)$$
>   $$(2n - 1)!! = (2n-1)(2n-3)(2n-5)....3(1)$$

But the second one wasn't at all helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Use that for all $k < l$, we have $(2k)!! \mid (2l)!!$, since there are just more factors. Thus the denominator is just $$4018!!$$ Now try to find $x,y$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint, multiplying both sides by $(2n)!!$, we have
$$
\dfrac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} \cdot \dfrac{(2n)!!}{(2n)!!} = \dfrac{(2n)!}{((2n)!!)^2} = \dfrac{(2n)!}{(2^n \cdot n!)^2} = \dfrac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} n! n!}  =  \dfrac{\binom{2n}{n}}{2^{2n}}
$$

Therefore, because the denominator is always a power of two, and the numerator is an integer, the entire sum will have a denominator that is a power of two. Therefore, $y=1$, and we now need to find $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $D_N$ be the denominator of $~~\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}~$ expressed in its lowest terms. Then $\log_2\dfrac{4^N}{D_N}$

forms the sequence described at [OEIS A$000120$](http://oeis.org/A000120).